# Encrypted and signed MIME messages using RFC 1847

Tags: php, encryption, sockets, gnupg, openpgp

I need a client-server encryption solution for web transfer, (i.e. signed and encrypted client-side, and verified and decrypted server-side).

I am using HTTP, but SSL is not available due to shared hosting restrictions (my server is a shared host environment).
Looking into alternative solutions, I have decided on OpenPGP using [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/). One of the reasons is that it is supported in PHP through various PEAR and PECL modules (PHP is the language I intend to use for *both* my client script and my server script, though Perl is also available as a last resort).

I am now trying to decide on the best way to transmit the data. I have come across [RFC 1847](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1847), which defines encrypted and signed multipart MIME messages. This protocol is extended specifically for PGP in [RFC 3156](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3156). (I think these protocols are related to the S/MIME encrypted email protocol).

My question is: is there any reason to follow these standards? As far as protocols go, they look like sensible solutions, but are there any clients that actually use this protocol? For example, if I made a multipart/encrypted request to an Apache web server, will there be any easy way to retrieve the data? My tests using a PHP script made me think that PHP would be no use trying to decipher requests like these ($_POST data seems to come from 'multipart/form-data' MIME-type data).

As my host *will* let me open sockets, it *would* be possible for me to use PHP's socket programming API to write a PHP script to act as a server that will accept 'multipart/encrypted' and 'multipart/signed' HTTP requests, but this seems like overkill.

Any suggestions?

For more information on my problem, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022994/transfering-encrypted-data-server-to-server-between-2-php-scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - these protocols are related to enrypted mail protocol, using that in your case is a little bit of overkill and you wolud have to use OpenSSL php extension. Go with OpenPGP.

Since your client will be written in PHP - consider following scenarios:

### Scenario 1: create simple SOAP webservice

Server and Client methods would be the same:

- getPublicKey() - returns public key
- sendMessage(msg) - returns answer

### Scenario 2: use GET/POST message

- Client -> HTTP GET (send me your
  public key) -> Server
- Client <- (my
  public key is xxxx) <- Server
- Client
  encrypts message with server's public
  key Client adds own public key to the
  message
- Client -> HTTP POST (sends
  encrypted message) -> Server
- Server
  decodes the message, and encodes
  answer with Clients public key
- Client
  <- (encoded answer to client) <-
  Server

Comment: Is OpenPGP better than OpenSSL? I am considering using a version of your second scenario with OpenSSL because these extensions are installed and otherwise I will have to nag my web hosts until they install PECL 'gnupg'.

Comment: OpenSSL is a SSL implementation and OpenPGP is a encryption algorithm, you cannot compare them. If you want to go with OpenSSL - check "openssl smime" parameters (encrypt, decrypt, sign, verify)